# Penrose-Moore Inverse is a special case of the Right-Inverse of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, pseudoinverse

In [this](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Reverse+Engineering+in+Control+Design-p-9781848215238) book (Alazard) it is said that a right inverse matrix $T^{\#}$ of a generic matrix $T$ may be written as:

$ T^{\#} = T^{+} + T^{\perp}X $

Where $T^{\perp}$ is an orthonormal basis of the null space of $T$ and $X$ is a matrix of free parameters.

I never came across such a general definition of a right inverse (I'm an engineer, so please pardon me!).
Where can I find an explanation of this? In my narrow view the right inverse was simply the Penroose-Moore pseudo-inverse and this general form is totally new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ being a right inverse of $T$ just means that $TA=I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix on the codomain of $T$. A given matrix may or may not have a right inverse.

The Moore-Penrose inverse $T^+$ *of a right-invertible matrix* is indeed a right inverse, but the Moore-Pensrose inverse is defined for all matrices, including those that have no right-inverse, thus it is not a special case of the right-inverse.

To see that for a right-invertible matrix, $T^\#$ is indeed a right inverse, you can just calculate:
$$TT^\# = T(T^+ + T^\bot X) = TT^+ + TT^\bot X = I +0X = I$$
Note that this uses the relation $TT^+=I$ which obviously is only true for right-invertible matrices.

Conversely if $T^+$ and $S$ are both right inverses of $T$, then $T(S−T^+)=0$, hence $S−T^+$ takes its values from the kernel, and thus it can be written as $T^\bot X$ for some matrix $X$.

Comment: Conversely, if $T^+$ and $S$ are both right inverses of $T$, then $T(S-T^+)=0$, hence $S-T^+$ takes its values from the kernel, and thus it can be written as $T^\perp X$ for some matrix $X$.

Comment: @Berci: Right, I forgot about the other direction. Do you mind if I just copy your comment in the post?

Comment: Absolutely not.

Comment: @Berci: Thank you, added.